# mongo dot notation ambiguity

Tags: mongodb, syntax, mongodb-query

I love MongoDB, and a certain little ambiguity occurred to me and I was wondering if anyone had seen this before and possibly would know the answer :-).

in mongo, to reach into sub-objects, you use dot notation, for example:

```
db.persons.find({ "address.state" : "CA" })
```

which is simple enough. How (if it does at all)  does mongo deal with the difference between:

```
{
    "address" { "state" : "CA" }
}
```

and

```
{
    "address.state" : "CA"
}
```

since dots are legal in keys as far as i know. Additionally, I believe that this would be a legal doc as well:

```
{
    "address" { "state" : "A" },
    "address.state" : "B"
}
```

in which case, I can see this query returning either `"A"` or `"B"`:

```
db.persons.find({}, {"address.state"}) // all docs selecting address.state as result.
```

Similar potential issue can arise I imagine with arrays as well:

```
{"a":["test"]}
```

which could be access with:

```
{"a.0"}
```

and of course

```
{"a" {"0" : "test"} }
```

which would also be access with:

```
{"a.0"}
```

thoughts? experiences? Is the conventional wisdom simply not to do that?

Comment: What happens when you try these queries in the mongo shell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A key such as "address.state" isn't legal. From [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names):

> Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. **`.`**) or null characters, and they must not start with a dollar sign (i.e. **`$`**).

Comment: I looked on the mongo site, but did not see it, that completely answers the question :-).