# MongoDb $match for embedded document

Tags: mongodb

```
db.entities.aggregate([$match : {"Company.Id" : {$gt : 11}}])
```

above code works in mongo shell but below does not work why ??

```
db.entities.aggregate([{$match : {Company : {Id : {$gt : 11}}}}])
```

it displays nothing.

Here is my mongodocument

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("552ca154993cfc98fef1e13c"),
 "Name" : "R",
 "Address" : "RAdd",
"Company" : {
     "Name" : "something",
     "Id" : 14
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongo dot notation ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333540/mongo-dot-notation-ambiguity)

Comment: no that's not what i meant..! what i wanted to know is in case of $project i am able to access embedded document as 
    db.entities.aggregate([{$project : {Company : {Name : 1}}}])
but in case of match 
    db.entities.aggregate([{$match : {Company : {Id : {$gt : 11}}}}])
will not give me any result why ??

Comment: @pilku: you didn't write ***anything*** about `$project` in your original question. Are we supposed to guess? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mongodb [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents)

When the field holds an embedded document, a query can either specify an exact match on the embedded document or specify a match by individual fields in the embedded document using the dot notation.

So this will work

```
db.entities.aggregate([{
       '$match':{
             "Company" : {
                 "Name" : "something",
                 "Id" : 14
                 }
             }
       }
])
```

Comment: `db.entities.aggregate([{$match : {Company : { Name : "something"}}}])`
-Gives no result 
`db.entities.aggregate([{$match : {"Company.Name" : "something"}}])`
-Gives result

Comment: It should be an exact match on the embedded document and not on the individual fields. If you are using an individual field you need to use the dot notation.

Comment: hmm yes i tried same with find and same output. but why not with $project?? i mean with $project [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#embedded-document-fields)

Comment: Yes It is allowed for `$project` [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#embedded-document-fields). I guess that is because for performing a match operation it looks for the `{ <field>: <value> }` condition trying to match it with Company and not with Name, while projection just passes along the documents with the specified fields to the next stage in the pipeline.

Comment: 1. How can we convert this above query to java? 


2. Let suppose I have Map<String, Object> obj which having the structure below json then how can we construct the above query with respect to map object.
    ```{ "Company" : {
                     "Name" : "something",
                     "Id" : 14
                     }
                 }```

Comment: @MukeshKumarGupta, it should be the same way you create a [document](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/?org/bson/Document.html). So something like `new Document("Company", new Document("Name", "something").append("Id", 14))`.