# Aggregate function error

Tags: mongodb

```
db.statements.aggregate([{$group : {"statement.object.id" : "http://lesson?id=ty_2", average_score_ty_2 : {$avg : "statement.result.subject.marks" }}}]);
```

When I am typing this on my AWS server. It is showing me error:

> $group's field names cannot contain '.'",

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to filter documents on the field `"statement.object.id"` equal to `"http://lesson?id=ty_2"` and then aggregate all or grouped documents to get the accumulated average `average_score_ty_2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongo dot notation ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333540/mongo-dot-notation-ambiguity)